# pass parameter into subprocess.Popen arguments

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, popen

I am new to Python and have some needs to write a script.

I have a parameter `result` and I need to pass it to argument in a `subprocess.Popen`

tried to do like this

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['sed', '-i', '/x/c\y = 'result'', 
                         '/home/test/1.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

but it gives a syntax error. If I go like this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['sed', '-i', '/x/c\y = ', result, 
                         '/home/test/1.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

sed wrongly implements the result, not like the ending of `/x/c\y =` but like a separate value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to concatenate strings using the `+` operator

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['sed', '-i', '/x/c\y = 'result'', ...\
                                                ^      ^
```

to

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['sed', '-i', '/x/c\y = '+result+'', ...\
```

Answer (score 1):

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("sed -i /x/c\y = "+result+" /home/test/1.txt",shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

You can try with shell=True option as well if you are using sed from its default location.